# Custom Cell Width?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How would I go about creating a custom cell width and corner radius? I want to have the cell 10 px from the leading and trailing and also have the corners rounded. I am unsure what view I would make these changes to for this desired effect. I want it to also clip the slide functions + the selection background as shown in the photo below.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set a width for your `tableViewCell`. It takes up the whole width of your `tableView`.

What you can do is to layout properly the subviews of the cell, according to the width you desire.

Let's solve your problems one by one.

---

> I want to have the cell 10 px from the leading and trailing and also
>   have the corners rounded.

For this, you would want to add constraints to your container view's leading and trailing with 10pts. That's it.

For rounding corners, you will be working on your view's layers, like so:

```
    someView.layer.cornerRadius     = 4.0
    someView.layer.borderWidth      = 1.0
    someView.layer.borderColor      = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

---

> I am unsure what view I would make these changes to for this desired
>   effect.

There are lots of ways to do this. One way is to use `UIStackView`, and the other one is using a simple `UIView` that will act as your *container*.

So based on your screenshot, the view hierarchy of your cell might go like this:

UITableViewCell --> ContentView of the cell --> ContainerView (skyblue) + Button.

---

> I want it to also clip the slide functions + the selection background
>   as shown in the photo below.

You can make an `IBOutlet` or reference of your trailing constraint and toggle its constant value.